# toggling attribute value of anchor tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have this HTML.

```
<a href="#" class="button redB" style="margin: 4px 4px 4px -4px;" id="estEditItemToggleMode" data-mode="edit">
    <img src="images/icons/light/check.png" alt="" class="icon">
    <span>Enable Editing Mode</span>
</a>
```

on click i want to keep toggling the value of `class` attribute and `data-mode`
it should go like this

```
if(mode == "edit") {
    class = "button blueB";
    data-mode = "select";
}
else if(mode == "select") {
    class = "button redB";
    data-mode = "edit";
}
```

i tried using this.

```
$('#estEditItemToggleMode').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).data('mode') == "edit") {
        $(this).removeClass('redB').addClass('blueB');
        $(this).attr('data-mode', 'select');
    }
    else if($(this).data('mode') == "select") {
        $(this).removeClass('blueB').addClass('redB');
        $(this).attr('data-mode', 'edit');
    }
});
```

this toggle the values only once. and hence no effect on two or more click. how to go with this correctly.

Comment: e.preventDefault();
  can u remove this line and try ?

Comment: tried it, even still it toggles only one time :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/UMpEq/1/)

```
$('#estEditItemToggleMode')
     .data('mode', 'edit') //added data to the link
     .live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);
        var mode = $this.data('mode');

        if(mode == "edit") {
            $this.removeClass('redB').addClass('blueB');
            $this.data('mode', 'select'); //Changed from .attr to .data
        }
        else if(mode == "select") {
            $this.removeClass('blueB').addClass('redB');
            $this.data('mode', 'edit'); //Changed from .attr to .data
        }
 });
```

and remove the attr `data-mode` from the markup.

```
<a href="#" class="button redB" style="margin: 4px 4px 4px -4px;" id="estEditItemToggleMode" >
    <img src="images/icons/light/check.png" alt="" class="icon">
    <span>Enable Editing Mode</span>
</a>
```

**Edit:** Cached some redundant jQuery calls.

**Edit 2:** `.live` is deprecated so you should either use `.on` or `.delegate`

**Edit 3:** Fiddle output,

[image]

Comment: nope it does not work , i got the solution myself, i had to change in the if condition to `$(this).attr('data-mode')`, anyway +1 for your effort. it works now, after trying and posting the question.

Comment: this does not change the value of `data-mode` although class toggles.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar attr and data are different, you cannot mix them like that.. either you need to use `.data / .attr`. What you are trying to see is `.attr`, but using `.data` is recommended. See updated post.

Comment: i tested the new code too, but for whatever reason only the class is being toggled, the value of `data-mode` is never changed. you can try out yourself. and in jsfiddle demo too only class is being change not the value of data-mode.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar It works fine for me.. Verified in console and see the image in the post. It is logged on each click. >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/UMpEq/1/ <<

Comment: yes it works, so i don't get the logic of removing data attribute from html markup, is it that you are creating dynamic data-attribute via jQuery? sorry i am poor in jQuery :)

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar it is not an attribute, but a simple arbitrary data that you can associate with a DOM element. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/  . If you want to see it visually by inspecting DOM in firebug then you need to use .attr() and keep the data-mode attr in the markup.. but as i mentioned earlier using .data is recommended.

Comment: one more thing i forgot i want to toggle the value inside of a tag too. `<span>Enable Editing Mode</span>` how do i change the value within.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar You should post that as new question, but it is really easy so here it goes. `$this.find('span').text('Value you wanted to change')` -> Insert this inside the if and else that should toggle the `span` text. Use `.html` inplace of `.text` incase if you are adding a html content inside the span.